# How can we fix Hat Dash?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, hatdash

I'm on a [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) 13 inches and when trying to play on Safari, as soon as a tap my spacebar, the page scroll down, and I can't see anything from the game. Has anyone found a solution? How can I report that bug?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: You can ask this in [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Did you try on Internet Explorer 6?

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357936/unable-to-play-hat-dash-in-safari-14/358000#358000 ?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I've ask the question on meta.stackexchange as proposed by @rene https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358308/907012

Comment: Deleting my previous comments and mentioning that this seems to me to be Safari specific; I can't reproduce in Chrome.